Pandas Convert Headers to DOW and Count?
I have a CSV file which currently has a format



Unnamed
1/1/24
1/2/24
etc




Person 1
NaN
Assignment1
etc


Person 1
NaN
Assignment2
etc


Person 2
Assignment 1
NaN
etc



Currently what I am doing is as follows...
df = pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv')
names = df.melt('Unnamed')['Unnamed']
values = df.melt('Unnamed')['value']
proc = pd.crosstab(names, values)

To get me an output



Name
Assignment 1
Assignment 2
etc




Person 1
1
1
etc


Person 2
1
1
etc



To calculate the number of each assignment for each person.  All is working well.
What I want to do is also now include the day of the week so my output will look like



Name
Assignment 1 Monday
Assignment 1 Tuesday
etc




Person 1
0
1
etc


Person 2
1
0
etc



Basically I want to add the day of week to each column (so 7 columns per assignment).  What is the easiest way to do this? Thanks!

Are "etc." only other dates?

Yes, sorry.  In the CSV there is a column per day.

You can add a second column to your crosstab for the columns, after converting to_datetime and getting the day_name:
tmp = df.melt('Unnamed', var_name='date')

# crosstab with a MultiIndex for the columns
out = pd.crosstab(tmp['Unnamed'].rename('Name'),
                  [tmp['value'], pd.to_datetime(tmp['date'], format='%m/%d/%y')
                                   .dt.day_name()])

# flatten the MultiIndex
out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]} {x[1]}')

# index as columns
out.reset_index(inplace=True)

Note that the order of the columns will be sorted in lexicographic order of the day names. If you want the natural order, you could add a extra level with the weekday:
tmp = df.melt('Unnamed', var_name='date')

date = pd.to_datetime(tmp['date'], format='%m/%d/%y')

out = pd.crosstab(tmp['Unnamed'].rename('Name'),
                  [tmp['value'], date.dt.weekday, date.dt.day_name()])

# we don't use the second level in the final name
out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]} {x[2]}')

out.reset_index(inplace=True)

Output:
       Name  Assignment 1 Monday  Assignment1 Tuesday  Assignment2 Tuesday
0  Person 1                    0                    1                    1
1  Person 2                    1                    0                    0

Intermediate before MultiIndex flattening for the second approach:
value    Assignment 1 Assignment1        Assignment2       
date                0           1      4           0      4
date           Monday     Tuesday Friday      Monday Friday
Name                                                       
Person 1            0           1      1           1      1
Person 2            1           0      0           0      0


Thanks! I was banging my head against the wall.

You're welcome @EFaden, I also added an alternative to ensure the days are sorted in natural order
